Papersize - why does TeX add margins by default and how can I avoid them?
After reading the answers, the best hint is:"The classical TeX does not know the paper dimensions".
Why does TeX add margins left and top of the page and how can I avoid them?
TeX, not LaTeX!
    %papersize
\hsize=21cm
\vsize=29.7cm
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, {\bf consectetur adipisici elit}, {\it sed eiusmod tempor incidunt} ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris  nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat. Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse {\sl cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. }Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\bye

What I want to get is like
    %papersize
\parindent=0pt
\hsize=21cm
\vsize=29.7cm
\hoffset-2.5cm
\voffset-2.5cm
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, {\bf consectetur adipisici elit}, {\it sed eiusmod tempor incidunt} ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris  nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat. Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse {\sl cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. }Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\bye


the reference point is 1in from the top and 1in from the left so simply subtract those amounts (by 1in not 2.5cm)

David; As you know, I am "insisting". I would like to know, how to prevent TeX to do this, instead of correcting afterwards.

David: As you can see, TeX works not correct in this example. The text reaches over the paperwidth, so, the added margin from the left is not compensated at the right border.

There is no right border. You need to set \hsize to a width that fits leaving whatever space you want. Tex is just following the lengths to have set. It is acting as designed

the texbook says: You should be careful not to offset the output so much that it falls off the edge of the physical medium on which it is being printed, unless you know that such out-of-bounds activity won't cause trouble. so you are responsible for setting \hsize+\hoffset to keep the text in bounds.

Physical printers cannot print to the edge of the paper (expecially those as old as TeX), so some margin is needed.  Instead, covers (for example) are printed on larger sheets of paper and cut to size after printing.

One reason why margins are included by default may be because printers often need margins: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3503615/12180615

@JohnKormylo I was just typing the same thing!

@Kimball - It happens.  Good link, though.

@all Thanks for all the answers. They helped.

Isn't it strange, that the answers got some upvotes, but the question only  3 by now? I think, a question should be automatically upvoted with every vote for an answer. Wouldn't that be fair?

It's a long standing phenomenon: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9508/282702

@Kimball It is easy: Any question should be upvoted when an answer is upvoted.  I think, that would be easy to implement. Without questions, there would be no forum.

I don't think it's quite so simple, but feel free to make a post on Meta asking about/suggesting this.

@David Carlisle I think, there is no reference point "1in from the top and 1in from the left" in TeX (the program). See my answer below.

@MBE sorry your answer does not correspond to tex's implementation at all., \hsize and \vsize specify the size of the text block from an origin 1in from the top and left of the paper, and there is nothing related to A4 at all in the original tex program.

@MBE why do you think a question should be upvoted if an answer is? Each post is voted separately on its merits, whether question or answer.

@David Carlisle Questions should be upvoted because the one who answers profits from the question. This does not mean, that every question in itself is good. That may be discussed in comments or answers. As it is for me, it takes some courage, to bear the criticism that is at hand.  Questioners are sometimes naive or uninformed. That's why they are asking.  Please, I do not critisize the politeness of the experts. I just think it would be fair, to upvote an accepted question, just to encourage the questioners.

@David Carlisle To answer a question is, to accept it.

Well that's not how the site works.

2.5cm is not the same as an inch. Either give a more1 accurate metric conversion ...
\parindent=0pt
\hsize=21cm
\vsize=29.7cm
\hoffset-2.54cm
\voffset-2.54cm
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, {\bf consectetur adipisici elit}, {\it sed eiusmod tempor incidunt} ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris  nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat. Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse {\sl cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. }Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\bye

... or specify an inch ...
\parindent=0pt
\hsize=21cm
\vsize=29.7cm
\hoffset-1in
\voffset-1in
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, {\bf consectetur adipisici elit}, {\it sed eiusmod tempor incidunt} ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris  nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat. Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse {\sl cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. }Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\bye

In a comment, you say that you want to know how to stop TeX creating the margins rather than correcting them afterwards. This is understandable but impossible. This is just the way Knuth set the thing up. You can set the margins however you please, but you always begin with a 1" left and 1" top margin.
For the 'why?', you would have to ask Donald Knuth. That's what he decided, so that's the way it is2.
1I say 'more accurate' rather than 'accurate' because, as pointed out in comments, 2.54 cm is not, of course, exactly 1". But 2.54 cm is generally 'close enough' for most everyday purposes. Moreover, all TeX dimensions are approximations. If you use them in calculations, the accumulated inaccuracies can become obvious in the result, but just storing a dimension is sufficient. That is, if you need greater accuracy than 2.54 cm provides, you probably also need to use an extension which supports floating point, but the current question does not seem to require this.
2And, yes, I know how aggravating this answer is because I am usually on the receiving end of it. That it is true doesn't seem to help.

@all Thanks for all the answers. They helped.

@MBE you should consider accepting one so this question is shown as having a satisfactory answer. (to be clear: I am not urging you to accept mine. you should accept whichever you find most helpful.) to do this, you click the greyed-out tick/checkmark symbol thingy at the top left of the answer you want to accept. (right below the up/down voting buttons.) they even give you points for doing it :-).

I was undecided.. All were helpful and all added something good.  Isn't there a way too thank all the helpers and to give a summary, of how I profited from the answers?

@MBE well, you can upvote all the answers, but you can only accept one. you could write another answer and accept that one instead, but I wouldn't do that unless you have something to add. egreg usually gets the ticks ;).

For me it has some subtle irony, that the answers got 29 upvotes, but the question has got only 2  :-)

Amusingly 1in is NOT the same as 2.54cm for TeX.  The former is 72.26999pt (or 4736286sp) and the latter is 72.2698pt (4736274sp).  This is with Knuth TeX and with PDFTeX and with LuaTeX (tested on current TL2024).  To confirm they are different you can try \ifdim1in=2.54cm\relax EQUAL\else DISTINCT\fi.

and 72.27pt is still a third dimension 4736287sp.

@user691586 yes, but all dimensions in TeX are approximations. 'more accurate' just needs to be close enough.

@user691586 I've added a note re. floating point and accuracy in case anybody requires greater precision than 2.54 cm or TeX can provide. I don't think there's much point in improving the conversion without floating point, which is beyond the scope of this answer :-).

The why is relatively clear (at least to those of us encountering TeX in the 80s): plain.tex sets up for 1in margins on all sides on letter-sized paper, which is the standard for US paper printing. That origin at 1in,1in is doubtless one of many choices that, were Knuth to be starting from scratch now, would not have been made, but in the mean time we get what we get.

@DonHosek not being a member of that group, the why is not at all clear to me ;). the standard for US paper printing of what by whom? not books, surely? I don't know what facilities universities had for printing, but the capacity to print on A4 here seems rather more recent. a bit later, we had dot matrix printers. but they didn't print on regular paper (i.e. A4). they printed onto rolls of paper with holes each side and perforations to make the pages. you wouldn't have wanted a book printed that way, though. A4 was for photocopiers and typewriters.

Typewritten documents on letter-size paper were created with 1 inch margins on all sides.
Computer-generated documents followed those practices, as most word processors followed the same practice.
Tractor feed paper for dot matrix printers was (sometimes) set up with perforations for pages so that when you separated your pages and removed the tractor feed, you had letter-size paper (but some printers printed on much wider pages intending to be used for program listings which might have up to 132 characters per line.

Laser printers of various types were becoming common in college/university settings. There were DVI drivers for most laser printers that could be targetted (some did not support custom fonts, e.g., the Xerox 2700 series). There were also drivers for dot matrix printers, although MF/Computer Modern didn’t work well at resolutions under 300dpi (and sometimes even AT 300 dpi).

As said in comments, the origin of the paper was set by D. Knuth into 1in from the top and 1in from the left of the paper. Then you can move this point by \voffset and \hoffset values and create the pages of text by \vsize and \hsize with upper-left corner in this moved point. Setting these four TeX registers to appropriate values and knowing the paper dimensions gives the margins. The classical TeX does not known the paper dimensions so the right and bottom margins cannot be set by an internal register. Calculating with \hoffset, \hsize and given paper width yields to the right margin. The same for \voffset, \vsize, paper height and bottom margin.
The modern TeX engines can move the original point given by Knuth to another place using new registers \pdfvorigin and \pdfhorigin. For example OpTeX sets \pdfvorigin=0pt, \pdfhorigin=0pt, so user needs not to calculate with annoying 1in constant and the \voffset and \hoffset are top and left margins directly. LaTeX keeps the Knuth's decision of the placement of the origin point, i.e. it sets \pdfvorigin=1in, \pdfhorigin=1in.
If you create PDF output directly by the TeX engine (using pdf extension) then you have to set paper dimensions by \pdfpageheight and \pdfpagewidth pdfTeX registers. Then there can be macros which takes these values and sets top, botom, left, right margins by setting \voffset, \hoffset, \vsize, \hsize. For example OpTeX does this by the \margins macro.

Indeed - I think it's pretty clear that OpTeX gets this right and that's Knuth's original idea was sub-optimal - LaTeX though is stuck with it as any change would be almost impossible to manage whilst avoiding change to existing documents. (Plain of course will never change not least as Knuth's TeX doesn't have the required primitives here.)

Knuth's original idea for TeX was to produce a Text Book.  1" margins are sub-optimal for other purposes and for /modern/ unbound designs, but Knuth was designing for printing, binding and presentation cases where 1" margins were a good default, with adjustment permitted around that value.

@david I meant programmatically - having a non-zero origin is not a great idea. The physical requirement to have a margin is separate.

@all Thanks for all the answers. They helped.

You should be aware that \hsize and \vsize don't refer to the page dimensions, but only of the text block.
If you're using Knuth TeX (only with DVI output), setting the page dimensions is left to the device driver you use, for instance dvips for printing and xdvi for previewing.
Assuming that you want to completely fill an A4 sheet of paper with text, you can use \hoffset and \voffset to -1in, because the standard that all device drivers use (by Knuth's decree) is that the origin is one inch right and one inch down the upper left angle of the paper.
Example code for fullpage.tex
\magnification=\magstephalf % just for experimenting

\hoffset=-1truein
\voffset=-1truein

\hsize=21truecm
\vsize=29.7truecm


\input plipsum

\lipsum{1-25}

\bye

Running
tex fullpage && xdvi -paper a4 fullpage

will show

The option for dvips is similar, but it's called -t. However, your TeX installation might already have ISO A4 paper output by default.
This has a small drawback, but it shouldn't be a problem for xdvi or dvips: you may need to adjust \hoffset or \voffset if the device driver has strange ideas about where to place the output (it happened in the olden days).
I used true dimensions just by way of example: it's better to use them because you may want to set a \magnification factor.
With pdftex the method is different. If you again want to fill a whole A4 sheet of paper, instead of \hoffset and \voffset you should use \pdfhorigin and \pdfvorigin. You can specify the page dimensions with \pdfpaperwidth and \pdfpaperheight.
The example code would become as follows. As also said in the comments, ISO A4 might already be the default so you don't need to specify it.
\magnification=\magstephalf % just for experimenting

\pdfhorigin=0pt
\pdfvorigin=0pt

% A4 paper is usually the default for TeX Live
% except in the US
%\pdfpagewidth=21truecm
%\pdfpageheight=29.7truecm

\hsize=21truecm
\vsize=29.7truecm


\input plipsum

\lipsum{1-25}

\bye


If you don't want to fill the page, but, say, have equal margins of 3cm on either side and 40 lines, with the top and bottom margin with a 2:3 ratio, you can measure 39 baseline skips (12pt), add the topsskip (10pt); the total is the desired \vsize. Subtract it from 29.7cm, divide by 5 and multiply by 2. No need to do calculations, because TeX can do them for us.
\magnification=\magstephalf % just for experimenting

% A4 paper is usually the default for TeX Live
% except in the US
%\pdfpagewidth=21truecm
%\pdfpageheight=29.7truecm

\hsize=15truecm
\vsize=\dimexpr\baselineskip*39+\topskip\relax

\pdfhorigin=\dimexpr(\pdfpagewidth-\hsize)/2\relax
\pdfvorigin=\dimexpr(\pdfpageheight-\vsize)*2/5\relax

\input plipsum

\lipsum{1-25}

\bye



@all Thanks for all the answers. They helped.

Thanks for your detailed answer. I upvoted it. Another question: Isn't it strange, that the answers got 29 upvotes, but the question only 2?  I think, a question should be automatically upvoted with every vote for an answer. Wouldn't that be fair?

@MBE Not necessaily - questions need to show 'sufficient research' and be 'objective' - one could argument your question should have been covered by reading  _The TeXbook (a requirement for plain users) and is a 'why' question, which don't have an objective answer that can be given by anyone other than the person who wrote the code (in this case DEK). Answers can 'hit the spot' even when questions don't.

@Joseph Wright Please, I do not want to be provocative, but
"Viewed 1k times " seems to show a common problem. But yes, it was a naive question, which I could have solved with better reading.
